# How much aerodynamic heating could we make without leaving the atmosphere?

Tags: aerodynamics

When an object goes beyond the speed of sound in air, it will heat up due to  the air in front of the object compressing. This can be seen for example during supersonic flights and during atmospheric reentry.

Spacecraft mostly accelerate to orbital velocity outside the atmosphere, hence why they heat up during reentry but not during lift off.

Excluding objects that accelerated or have received thrust outside the atmosphere, what has been the most aerodynamic heating achieved? And how much could we feasibly achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more precise with your question: You can either achieve high peak temperatures or lower peaks at the cost of higher overall heating. Normally, the pointed forward edges of supersonic aircraft show that here low overall heating is desired. However, the [blunt tips of hypersonic craft](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24414/why-when-is-the-blunt-nose-better/24424#24424) show the preference for lower peak loads.

The formula for [stagnation temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagnation_temperature) gives an indication of the possible peak temperature, which grows with the square of airspeed. Basically, the kinetic energy of the flow is changed to potential energy (pressure) which is accompanied by a temperature increase.  If [air is heated above approx. 2,000 K](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a224584.pdf) (PDF!), adding more energy will result in dissociation of the gas with less further heat increase. Above approximately 8000 K, Nitrogen will join in and now most energy will go into the dissociation process rather the heating of the gas.

Below the level where dissociation kicks in, the adiabatic temperature rise ∆T due to a deceleration from a speed v to zero is:
$$∆T = \frac{v^2}{2\cdot c_p}$$
where $c_p$ is the specific heat at constant pressure (unit $\frac{J}{kg\cdot K} = \frac{m^2}{s^2\cdot K}$). Note that this already happens at subsonic speed! If you are only interested in peak temperatures, start [high up in the atmosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermosphere) where static temperature can reach up to 1700°C, depending on solar activity, and go as fast as your [materials](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23760/how-do-fast-flying-aircraft-avoid-overheating/23761#23761) allow.

With the maximum heat load, things are more complicated. The amount of heat Q which gets transferred to our vehicle depends on the temperature increase, but also on the air density $\rho$ and the flow speed:
$$Q = v\cdot\rho\cdot c_p\cdot∆T$$
Denser air contains more heat energy, so the proportionality with density should make sense. But why speed? If the hot air is replenished at a faster rate, more heat can be transported to the vehicle's surface per unit of time. Now we have a heat flow which grows with the cube of flow speed, but that is not all. We still need to understand how density will be affected. When air is heated, density drops, but the flow at the forward facing parts of the vehicle is compressed as well, so density goes up in the end:
$$\frac{\rho}{\rho_{\infty}} = \left(1 + \frac{\kappa}{2}\cdot Ma^2\cdot c_p\right)^{\frac{1}{\kappa}}$$
with $\kappa$ as the ratio of the specific heats and $Ma$ the Mach number of the flow. Now things get messy because all parameters will change with temperature, so let me short-cut to [NACA report 1381](http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/reports/1958/naca-report-1381.pdf) which covers the re-entry heating of spheres. Here the rate of heat transfer is proportional to the cube of speed, so flying faster at constant dynamic pressure will cause a quadratic rise in the temperature of the surrounding air and a rate of heat transfer rising with the cube of speed due to convection.

Answer (score 1):

The most well-known example of aerodynamic heating is the Concorde, which flew at around and above Mach 2. Although it certainly isn't fastest aircraft ever built, the combination of its skin friction (and therefore drag), aerodynamic profile, and other factors, meant that it's outer temperature increased so much during flight that the aircraft itself was designed to accommodate several inches of expansion when in the air, quoted up to a full foot. (Its worth noting that this only around 5% of the full length of the Concorde)

As for how much heating could be achieved, there is theoretically no limit, if one were to use materials as rough as possible, and make the aerodynamic profile of the aircraft intentionally poor so as to increase drag.

Comment: The shape need not be "poor so as to increase drag." Aerodynamic heating is a function of leading-edge radius, and so an infinitely sharp (radius is zero) leading edge can cause a theoretically-infinite heating. Obviously in real life, things have finite radius, but drag isn't the only important factor.